# Which one is the better form to use with `whether`?

Tags: questions, optional-that, whether-if

> My question is whether...

Or

> My question is that whether...

Which one can be the best option?
For example, let’s say:

> My question is (that?) whether they have everything copied or not...

If it shouldn’t have `that`, in what case am I supposed to use it as well?

Comment: It is impossible to say for sure without the entire sentence, although *usually* the first one is better.

Comment: @stangdon Hi. For example, let’s say:

    My question is (that?) whether they have everything copied or not...

If it shouldn’t have `that`, in what case am I supposed to use it as well?

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable circumstance where "My question is that whether..." would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need "that". "My question is whether they have copied everything or not" is fine.

In general, you wouldn't use "that" to introduce a subordinate clause which is a question - you'd just use the question word itself, e.g. "My question is why anything was copied".